# "Undefined method `each' for '2,1':String" when using @partner.products association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a part file where I want to show all my products for a specific partner.
Here's the html.erb:

```
<% unless @products.nil? %>
        <% @products.each do |prod|%>
            <tr id="p_<%= prod.id%>">
                <td><%= prod.name %></td>
                <td><%= prod.price %></td>
                <td><%= number_field_tag "product_qty_input[#{prod.id}]", get_offer_product_qty(@offer.id, prod.id),:min => 0, :max => 99 %></td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But I keep getting the error: undefined method `each' for "2,1":String
it says it's on this line: <% @products.each do |prod|%>

But I don't see the problem..
Here's my controller:

```
def select_products
    @partner = Partner.find(params[:partner_id])
    if params[:id] == "-1"
      @offer = nil
    else
      @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    end

    @select_callback = url_for( @offer.nil? ? new_partner_offer_path(@partner) : [:edit, @partner, @offer] ) 
    @products = @partner.active_products
    @num_select = PRODS_PER_OFFER

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => "products/select"}
    end
  end
```

You see I have  @products = @partner.active_products method, but i changed that to see if it got there, and it's not, must be something before...

I would apreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Here is the method `active_products` :

```
def active_products
    self.products.where("active IS NOT NULL AND active = true")
end
```

It should be returning the object not string
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks @thesis

**UPDATE 2**
Guys, Thanks a lot for the help, and with the assistence of @thesis I figured it out.
It was actualy something that I haven't thought about before, and it wasn't describe here in the question.
My sessionkeeper helped me keep my form as I selected products in another page!
That was meesing it up!

Comment: Eww. Looks like a denormalized database: `@partner.active_products` is returning a *string* `"2,1"` **?!?** If "the relationship" is stored as text, e.g. Product ID's separated by commas, then it'll need to be monkey-pants'ed back to the [Product] objects using an additional query.

Comment: From "if it got there, and it's not, must be something before..": then, where *else* is `@products` set? It won't be set magically.

Comment: Not really @pst, active_products is just a method that returns products where partner_id is the one calling the method and the active attribute is true.

Comment: The *string* `"2,1"` **is** coming from somewhere. Verify that it is so at the exception site, and for which variable/expression, and then track that back from the exception site to where it is introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very simple. You have to fix your `active_products` method, as it returns `String`. In your case, string is `"2,1"` but you have to return collection of products, to iterate it with [each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) method.

For additional help, please update your question and add `active_products` instance method from `Partner` model.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! I just updated the question with the active_products method. It really should return the object Partner, right?

Comment: Please, add the line: `p @products` after `@products = @partner.active_products` and show me output from your log.

Comment: it printed the object and it's atributes:

[#<Product id: 1, name: "test", description: "desc test", price: 7, active: true, partner_id: 1, product_type_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-28 21:44:32", updated_at: "2012-05-28 21:44:32">]

That is when I edit the Offer, it works just fine! But when I try to create a new one I get the error, and it does not print anything on the Log.
This is what I get on the console:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for "1":String):

By the way, I dunno why now it's "1"...

Comment: It was actually a sessions thing... 
I got it working now!
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have products as numbers "2,1".

@partner.active_products should ideally return ActiveRecord::Relation, hence it should iterate objects of Product class.

Please go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

And before that, you may like to search for 'ruby philosophy' and 'rails philosophy'

Comment: Yes, @AmolPujari. It's what the error renders: undefined method `each' for "2,1":String